# How to solve Unresolved Compliation error in java?

Tags: java, port, serversocket

i am trying to start server for video conferencing but getting error while running.. so can anyone help me where is my mistake and how i start my server for clients to get connected with me..

```
     package chat;

     import java.awt.Button;
     import java.awt.Choice;
     import java.awt.Color;
     import java.awt.Component;
     import java.awt.Container;
     import java.awt.Event;
     import java.awt.Frame;
     import java.awt.Image;
     import java.awt.Insets;
     import java.awt.Label;
     import java.awt.List;
     import java.awt.MediaTracker;
     import java.awt.Menu;
     import java.awt.MenuBar;
     import java.awt.MenuItem;
     import java.awt.TextArea;
     import java.awt.TextComponent;
     import java.awt.Toolkit;
     import java.awt.Window;
     import java.io.IOException;
     import java.io.PrintStream;
     import java.net.ServerSocket;

     public class ChatServer extends Frame
     {
       static final int DEFAULT_USERCOUNT = 3;
       static final int DEFAULT_PORT = 10000;
       static final String ICON_FILE = "icon.gif";
     int num_Line = 0;
     User[] users = null;
     User_webBrowser[] users_webBrowser = null;
     User_Video[] users_Video = null;
    User_Audio[] users_Audio = null;
  ServerSocket ss = null;
     ServerSocket ss1 = null;
     ServerSocket ss2 = null;
     ServerSocket ss3 = null;
     RoomGroup roomGroup = null;
    int port = 10000;
     Image icon = null;
     String IP = null;
       TextArea message_TextArea;
       List users_List;
       Choice room_Choice;
       Label message_Label;
       Label room_Label;
       Label userList_Label;
       Button clean_Button;
       MenuBar mainMenuBar;
       Menu menu1;
       Menu menu3;

       void initServer(int port)
         throws IOException
       {
       this.users = new User[3];
       this.users_webBrowser = new User_webBrowser[3];
       this.users_Video = new User_Video[3];

       this.roomGroup = new RoomGroup(3, this.room_Choice, this);
         try {
         this.ss = new ServerSocket(port, 5);
         this.ss1 = new ServerSocket(port + 1, 5);
         this.ss2 = new ServerSocket(port + 2, 5);
         this.ss3 = new ServerSocket(port + 3, 5);
         this.message_TextArea.appendText(
           "\nserver socket init successed");
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
         this.message_TextArea.appendText(
           "\nserver socket init error" + e);
         }
       for (int i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++)
         {
         this.users[i] = new User(this, i);
         this.users_webBrowser[i] = new User_webBrowser(this, i);
        this.users_Video[i] = new User_Video(this, i);
         }

      this.roomGroup.setUsers(this.users);
       show();
       go();
      this.message_TextArea.appendText("\nserver started");
       }

       ChatServer(int port)
         throws IOException
       {
       this.icon = getToolkit().getImage("icon.gif");
       MediaTracker tracker = new MediaTracker(this);
       tracker.addImage(this.icon, 0);
         try {
         tracker.waitForAll();
        } catch (Exception e) {
         System.out.println(e);
         }

      setLayout(null);
      addNotify();
      resize(insets().left + insets().right + 544, insets().top + insets().bottom + 355);

      setTitle("Video conference system server V1.0");
      setIconImage(this.icon);

      setBackground(new Color(14542583));

      this.message_TextArea = new TextArea();
      this.message_TextArea.reshape(insets().left + 12, 
        insets().top + 36, 396, 240);
      add(this.message_TextArea);
      this.users_List = new List(5, false);
      add(this.users_List);
      this.users_List.reshape(insets().left + 432, insets().top + 
       144, 76, 110);
      this.room_Choice = new Choice();
      add(this.room_Choice);
      this.room_Choice.reshape(insets().left + 420, insets().top + 
        60, 100, 1);
      this.message_Label = new Label("Server Message");
      this.message_Label.reshape(insets().left + 36, insets().top + 
        12, 100, 24);
      add(this.message_Label);
      this.room_Label = new Label("Meeting Room");
      this.room_Label.reshape(insets().left + 420, insets().top + 
        14, 100, 24);
      add(this.room_Label);
      this.userList_Label = new Label("User Lists");
      this.userList_Label.reshape(insets().left + 420, insets().top + 
        108, 100, 28);
      add(this.userList_Label);
      this.clean_Button = new Button("Remove");
      this.clean_Button.reshape(insets().left + 180, insets().top + 
        12, 60, 24);
      add(this.clean_Button);

      this.mainMenuBar = new MenuBar();

      this.menu1 = new Menu("File");
      this.menu1.add("Restart");
      this.menu1.add("Quit");
      this.mainMenuBar.add(this.menu1);

      this.menu3 = new Menu("Help");
      this.mainMenuBar.setHelpMenu(this.menu3);
      this.menu3.add("About");
      this.mainMenuBar.add(this.menu3);
      setMenuBar(this.mainMenuBar);

      this.port = port;
      initServer(port);
       }

       ChatServer()
         throws IOException
       {
      this(10000);
       }

       void cleanButton_Clicked(Event event)
       {
      this.message_TextArea.setText("");
       }

       void About_Action(Event event)
       {
      new AboutDialog(this, true).show();
       }

       void Exit_Action(Event event)
       {
      new QuitDialog(this, true).show();
       }

       void Restart_Action(Event e)
       {
         try {
        quit();
        initServer(this.port);
        } catch (Exception e1) {
        this.message_TextArea.appendText("\ninit server error");
         }
       }

       public synchronized void show()
       {
      move(50, 50);

      super.show();
       }

       void roomChoice_Action(Event e)
       {
      String roomName = null;
      int roomID = 0;

      this.users_List.clear();
      roomName = this.room_Choice.getSelectedItem();
      roomID = this.roomGroup.getRoomID(roomName);
      for (int i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++)
        if ((this.users[i].logged) && (this.users[i].belongRoom) && 
          (this.users[i].roomID == roomID))
          this.users_List.addItem(this.users[i].name);
       }

       int roomNum()
       {
      String roomName = null;
      int roomID = 0;

      this.users_List.clear();
      roomName = this.room_Choice.getSelectedItem();
      roomID = 0;
      int k = 0;
      for (int i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
        if ((this.users[i].logged) && (this.users[i].belongRoom) && 
          (this.users[i].roomID == roomID)) {
         this.users_List.addItem(this.users[i].name);
          k++;
           }
         }
      return k;
       }

       public boolean handleEvent(Event event)
      {
      if (event.id == 201) {
        quit();
        hide();
        dispose();
        System.exit(0);
        return true;
        }
      if ((event.target == this.room_Choice) && (event.id == 
        1001)) {
        roomChoice_Action(event);
        return true;
        }
      if ((event.target == this.clean_Button) && (event.id == 
        1001)) {
        cleanButton_Clicked(event);
        return true;
         }

      return super.handleEvent(event);
       }

       public boolean action(Event event, Object arg)
       {
      if ((event.target instanceof MenuItem)) {
        String label = (String)arg;
        if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("About")) {
          About_Action(event);
         return true;
           }
       if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("Quit")) {
        Exit_Action(event);
         return true;
          }
       if (label.equalsIgnoreCase("Restart")) {
         Restart_Action(event);
         return true;
           }
         }
     return super.action(event, arg);
       }

       public static void main(String[] args)
       {
         try
         {
       chatServer = new ChatServer();
         }
         catch (Exception e)
         {
           ChatServer chatServer;
        System.out.println(e);
         }
       }

       public void go()
       {
      for (int i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
        this.users[i].start();
        this.users_webBrowser[i].start();
        this.users_Video[i].start();
         }
       }

       public void quit()
       {
     for (int i = 0; i < this.users.length; i++) {
       if (this.users[i] != null) this.users[i].destroy();
       if (this.users_webBrowser[i] != null) this.users_webBrowser[i].destroy();
       if (this.users_Video[i] != null) this.users_Video[i].destroy();
         }
         try
         {
        this.ss.close();
       this.ss = null;
        this.ss1.close();
        this.ss1 = null;
        this.ss2.close();
        this.ss2 = null;
        this.ss3.close();
        this.ss3 = null;
        this.room_Choice.removeAll();
        this.users_List.clear();
        this.message_TextArea.appendText(
          "\nserver socket closed");
         }
         catch (IOException e) {
       System.out.println(e);
         }
       }
     }
```

Stack Trace

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    chatServer cannot be resolved to a variable
    at chat.ChatServer.main(ChatServer.java:275)
```

Comment: Soo what's the error? Stack trace and a pointer to the right line?

Comment: 1. Reduce your code to the smallest possible runnable program that shows your problem. 2. Post the entire exception.

Comment: @pescis..do u have any idea where is mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The offending line is:

```
chatServer = new ChatServer();
```

in public static void main(String[] args)

But you had not previously declared the chatServer variable.

Try:

```
try {
  ChatServer chatServer = new ChatServer();
} catch (Exception e) {
  System.out.println(e);
}
```

Comment: I already try this @NickJ but still the same error..

Comment: Well you get the error when you try to run a Java program with compilation errors. What do the actual compilation errors say?

Comment: That is in stacktrace bro.. see my stacktrace that is under the code with line number..

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: chatServer cannot be resolved to a variable

Comment: You misunderstand. When you attempt to compile a Java program, you might get compile-time errors. If you get such an error, but you try to run it anyway, you'll get a run-time error. The error you have posted is the run-time error you'd get. Are you using an IDE like Eclipse or Netbeans, are just using javac on the command line?

Comment: Anyway, my answer would work. There must be something else wrong as well.

Comment: then what should i do? and i am using eclipse IDE